# What's a simple way of warping an image with a given set of points?

Tags: math, graphics, morphing

I'd like to implement image morphing, for which I need to be able to deform the image with given set of points and their destination positions (where they will be "dragged"). I am looking for a simple and easy solution that gets the job done, it doesn't have to look great or be extremely fast.

This is an example what I need:

Let's say I have an image and a set of only one deforming point [0.5,0.5] which will have its destination at [0.6,0.5] (or we can say its movement vector is [0.1,0.0]). This means I want to move the very center pixel of the image by 0.1 to the right. Neighboring pixels in some given radius r need to of course be "dragged along" a little with this pixel.

My idea was to do it like this:

1. I'll make a function mapping the source image positions to destination positions depending on the deformation point set provided.
2. I will then have to find the inverse function of this function, because I have to perform the transformation by going through destination pixels and seeing "where the point had to come from to come to this position".

My function from step 1 looked like this:

```
p2 = p1 + ( 1 / ( (distance(p1,p0) / r)^2 + 1 ) ) * s
```

where

- p0 ([x,y] vector) is the deformation point position.
- p1 ([x,y] vector) is any given point in the source image.
- p2 ([x,y] vector) is the position, to where p1 will be moved.
- s ([x,y] vector) is movement vector of deformation point and says in which direction and how far p0 will be dragged.
- r (scalar) is the radius, just some number.

I have problem with step number 2. The calculation of the inverse function seems a little too complex to me and so I wonder:

- If there is an easy solution for finding the inverse function, or
- if there is a better function for which finding the inverse function is simple, or
- if there is an entirely different way of doing all this that is simple?

Answer (score 3):

Here's the solution in Python - I did what [Yves Daoust](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1196549/yves-daoust) recommended and simply tried to use the forward function as the inverse function (switching the source and destination). I also altered the function slightly, changing exponents and other values produces different results. Here's the code:

```
from PIL import Image
import math

def vector_length(vector):
  return math.sqrt(vector[0] ** 2 + vector[1] ** 2)

def points_distance(point1, point2):
  return vector_length((point1[0] - point2[0],point1[1] - point2[1]))

def clamp(value, minimum, maximum):
  return max(min(value,maximum),minimum)

## Warps an image accoording to given points and shift vectors.
#  
#  @param image input image
#  @param points list of (x, y, dx, dy) tuples
#  @return warped image

def warp(image, points):
  result = img = Image.new("RGB",image.size,"black")

  image_pixels = image.load()
  result_pixels = result.load()

  for y in range(image.size[1]):
    for x in range(image.size[0]):

      offset = [0,0]

      for point in points:
        point_position = (point[0] + point[2],point[1] + point[3])
        shift_vector = (point[2],point[3])

        helper = 1.0 / (3 * (points_distance((x,y),point_position) / vector_length(shift_vector)) ** 4 + 1)

        offset[0] -= helper * shift_vector[0]
        offset[1] -= helper * shift_vector[1]

      coords = (clamp(x + int(offset[0]),0,image.size[0] - 1),clamp(y + int(offset[1]),0,image.size[1] - 1))

      result_pixels[x,y] = image_pixels[coords[0],coords[1]]

  return result

image = Image.open("test.png")
image = warp(image,[(210,296,100,0), (101,97,-30,-10), (77,473,50,-100)])
image.save("output.png","PNG")
```

[image: morph]

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to construct the direct function and invert it. Directly compute the inverse function, by swapping the roles of the source and destination points.

You need some form of bivariate interpolation, have a look at radial basis function interpolation. It requires to solve a linear system of equations.

Inverse distance weighting (similar to your proposal) is the easiest to implement but I am afraid it will give disappointing results.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_interpolation#Irregular_grid_.28scattered_data.29